# Avoid busy wait in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm doing a thing in Access 2003 and VBA. I do lots of iteration and sometimes something happens and I would like to halt and notify the user, but not with a MsgBox but in a text field.

So, I print a message in it and use a loop that checks a global "hold" boolean. With DoEvents, Windows checks for KeyDown and if it is there, hold is set to False and iteration continues.

But, I suspect there is a better way, because isn't that an example of "busy waiting"? Although it is not that "busy", just a boolean check, it is busy enough for my computer to start make sounds, and the overall impression is not robust.

Is there a way to just wait (do nothing) and then continue on a key down interrupt?

Comment: That would be possible but I don't want a pop up message box because it is disruptive. Imagine for example if you want to hit C (for "continue iteration") like 10 or 15 times. I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Your solution seems good and I understand what you mean by the constant boolean check making the machine busy in a sense, unfortunately this is probably the best way to wait and check for a key down event constantly

Comment: If you are displaying some info to the user and want to wait for 'a key down interrupt', why is pressing Enter to close a MsgBox not acceptable?

Comment: Like I said, it is disruptive. A MsgBox is good when you expect the user to actually read the stuff in it, think, and then make a choice. But in my case, in almost all of the cases the user will know what is going on, sometimes he will want to pause, but otherwise just "fast forward" (like 20 "Continue" answers in a row) - in such a case, a flickering MsgBox (zap zap zap) will only make your eyes dizzy. Probably, the best solution would be an advanced MsgBox where you could fine tune exactly what you want to do. But so far there is no need for that so I wanted to do it the way I described it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use a msgbox, you can define your own form with a textbox on it and the appropriate code.  Open this form with a parameter of acDialog and it will halt the code the same as a msgbox

Comment: I'm not using a MsgBox. That's the thing: if I were, halt would be implicit, right? You solution sounds like making my own MsgBox. I don't see the purpose of that since if I wanted a MsgBox, why wouldn't I use the built-in MsgBox? (Or maybe I misinterpreted you?) I'm very happy to dump the log output in the text field, only sometimes I want to halt execution and wait for input. The global variable and the "busy wait" loop achieves this, but as I said I'm not happy with that solution.